# Define spaces for responsive design with CSS

Tags: html, css, frames

*Hi Guys,*

I want to make a website with CSS. However, I have problems with the design. I have different areas. The header, which is independent. And then the "main area", which consists of a left frame, a center frame and a right frame. As you can see in the code, I have defined the distance as '1.75%'. As I show it here, it is (in my opinion) already almost perfect.

I now have the following problem:

I want to pay attention to a recursive design. If I use this page as it is and shrink the browser window to the left until it is no longer possible, all spacing is correct.
As you can see, there are no spaces between the frames in the middle.
As soon as I try to get the same distance of '1.75%' between these 3 with e.g. 'margin-top' or 'margin-bottom', it shifts the distances when zooming out.

Can you please take a look and help me?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 95%;
}

body {
  background-image: url(Pics/XXX.jpg);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  font: 100.01% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: #ff0;
  margin: 0;
}

a:link {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:visited {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

a:hover {
  color: #B58900;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
}

.Site {
  border: 0px dotted #192F3D;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 4%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Site_Container {
  border: 1px dotted #192F3D;
  height: 75%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------- */

.Site_Container_L {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px dotted #192F3D;
  width: 15.5%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.Site_Container_M {
  float: left;
  border: 0px dotted #192F3D;
  width: 67%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.Site_Container_R {
  float: left;
  border: 1px dotted #192F3D;
  width: 15.5%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------- */

.Header {
  border: 1px dotted #192F3D;
  height: 15%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------- */

.Links {
  border: 1px dotted #192F3D;
  height: 12%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------- */

.Container {
  border: 1px dotted #192F3D;
  height: 76%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------- */

.Border {
  border: 1px dotted #192F3D;
  height: 12%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------- */

.Seperator {
  border: 0px dotted #192F3D;
  height: 1.75%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="Site">

  <div class="Header">

  </div>

  <div class="Site_Container">

    <div class="Site_Container_L">
    </div>

    <div class="Site_Container_M">

      <div class="Links">

      </div>

      <div class="Container">

      </div>

      <div class="Border">

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="Site_Container_R">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: It's *responsive* design. Not *recursive*

Comment: You should really try to clarify what's that you don't like with the current *design* - and what is the desired result. From your current explanation — it's hard to tell...

Comment: Actually my design looks like this :
https://ibb.co/FJcPyRP
Minimized, it looks like this :
https://ibb.co/V36gKs7

After i inserted :
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;

into ".Container", it looks like this :
https://ibb.co/C5DF25r

The problem is, ifi'm now minimizing the browser window,
it looks like this :
https://ibb.co/cTxFcY8

How can i define the space without breaking the responsive design ?

Comment: What about [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) that sets back `margin-top: 1%; margin-bottom: 1%;` to `0%` on mobiles?

Comment: Can you give me an example please ? Do you mean :
`@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
margin-top: 0%;
margin-bottom:0%;
}`

Comment: Please edit your question to include illustrations of what you expect to happen (or want to happen) versus what is actually happening.

Comment: @ Brett Donald :
I don't know what's so hard on my question to understand ? I already posted the CSS and the HTML in my original post. Just copy and save it and open it in a web browser. In the mid frame there are 3 seperate frames. They are called "Links" , "Container" and Border ? I want to have spaces between Links and Container, also between Container and Border, which are as large as all other spaces ( 1% ). But without breaking the responsive design.

Comment: @Brett Donald : IT should look like this :
https://ibb.co/HqqfsQ2
But if i shrink the browser, it looks like :
https://ibb.co/wKWwy7N

Comment: Many of these image links are broken, so we still can’t easily understand the problem. You, as the one asking the question, need to make every effort possible to make your question easily understood and efficiently answered. You should edit your question to improve it, rather than trying to clarify it in the comments. Remember that the question needs to stand the test of time — it needs to be useful to someone else in five years’ time. Include any images within the text of your question — Stack Overflow has integrated image hosting — which is better than trying to reference external images.

Comment: Please give an e - mail adress, i can use and i will send you the zipped files. I guess, that's the easiest way.